# Stealthcoin compared to Monero

Tags: cryptocurrency-comparison

How does Monero compare to Stealthcoin https://stealth.org/

I mean in what ways is Monero better other than it being an older cryptocurrency?

thanks

Comment: Looks like a premine "Blocks 1–10: 23300 XST per Block; Blocks 11- 260: 16 XST per Block; Blocks 261+: 8000 XST per Block" Could be misinterpreting it though

Comment: Monero is real and functioning. The thing you linked to is full of hyperbole and plans. There's really nothing quite to "compare".

Comment: After reading `Quantum` and `Proof-of-Stake` I lost interest.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. *jtgrassie* I think Stealth Coin does exist. If they are still in development how do they have a currency name XST ? You can also buy and sell it. And there is a wallet, and it can be used with Ledger too. https://coinswitch.co/info/stealth/what-is-stealth They have a payment system for merchants to use, https://www.stealthpay.com/ Stealthcoin wallet
https://stealthcointalk.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=54&sid=b83d57ab1c76329b84c2b6e05f49c472

Answer (score 1):

1. Stealth.org is a nice pricey domain
2. Stealthcoin = PoS vs Monero = PoW
3. Stealthcoin optimizes coinbase rewards to allow very rapid blocks, tradeoff being staker centralization*

* You can only withdraw after mining (staking) *the equivalent* of a full day worth of blocks, meaning in 1 year, the best case scenario is 365 people get to withdraw.

The project will likely have to age before a fair comparison is really doable.